# command line byte sequence

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

How do you express a byte sequence from the command line? 
i.e like you would in PHP with the following:

```
<?php
echo "\xC2\xA3"
```

usage: for passing a Unicode string to a script or program. The above example is the UK pound sign "£"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo -e "\xC2\xA3"
```

or

```
echo $'\xc2\xa3'
```

the latter may be bash-specific, I don't remember.

Comment: The former is bash (or rather, echo) specific too. Use the more portable `printf` utility instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf "\xC2\xA3"
£
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding the echo abomination and using the Standard Tool designed for that purpose.